# R как очистить таблицу перед записью в нее новых значений?

Tags: база-данных, r

есть запрос, результаты которого записываются в базу данных при помощи dbWriteTable.
мне нужно, чтобы перед записью очищались старые данные. как это сделать?
спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В методе `dbWriteTable` предусмотрен аргумент `overwrite`, который вызывает `dbRemoveTable` перед записью.

```
dbWriteTable(con, table_name, my_data_frame, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Также перед записью можно вручную очистить таблицу с помощью вызова:

```
dbExecute(con, "TRUNCATE TABLE table_name")
```

Запись затем можно осуществить с помощью вызова:

```
dbWriteTable(con, table_name, my_data_frame, append = TRUE)
```

Последний вариант может быть полезен, если вы хотите сохранить структуру таблицы, в противном случае структура таблицы будет определена на основании типов в R, если не задать их вручную в аргументе `field.types`.

Answer (score 0):

При чтении таблицы нужно указать `overwrite=TRUE`